# Gnuplot - 3D Surface Graph

Tags: drawing, gnuplot

I am trying to create a 3D surface plot which looks like this:
[image]

Instead of plotting the equation, I am trying to plot my own set of data contained in the data.tsv file in the recommended grid format.

```
8417    5128    4661
7284    4940    3373
5220    3597    4088
```

For clarity, The XYZ representation of the above data is:

```
rec/s   mb/s    latency
640000  1024    5220
640000  2048    3597
640000  4096    4088
320000  1024    7284
320000  2048    4940
320000  4096    3373
160000  1024    8417
160000  2048    5128
160000  4096    4661
```

The gnuplot script that I am using to get the desired output is:

```
set term postscript eps enhanced color 
set output '|ps2pdf - outputfile.pdf'
set bar 1.000000 front
set style circle radius graph 0.02, first 0.00000, 0.00000 
set style ellipse size graph 0.05, 0.03, first 0.00000 angle 0 units xy
set style textbox transparent margins  1.0,  1.0 border
unset logscale
set samples 51, 51
set isosamples 21, 21
set style data lines
unset paxis 1 tics
unset paxis 2 tics
unset paxis 3 tics
unset paxis 4 tics
unset paxis 5 tics
unset paxis 6 tics
unset paxis 7 tics
set title "3D gnuplot demo" 
set xlabel "X axis" 
set xlabel  offset character -3, -2, 0 font "" textcolor lt -1 norotate
set xrange [ 160000 : 640000 ] noreverse nowriteback
set ylabel "Y axis" 
set ylabel  offset character 3, -2, 0 font "" textcolor lt -1 rotate by -270
set yrange [ 1024 : 4096 ] noreverse nowriteback
set zlabel "Z axis" 
set zlabel  offset character -5, 0, 0 font "" textcolor lt -1 norotate
set paxis 1 range [ * : * ] noreverse nowriteback
set paxis 2 range [ * : * ] noreverse nowriteback
set paxis 3 range [ * : * ] noreverse nowriteback
set paxis 4 range [ * : * ] noreverse nowriteback
set paxis 5 range [ * : * ] noreverse nowriteback
set paxis 6 range [ * : * ] noreverse nowriteback
set paxis 7 range [ * : * ] noreverse nowriteback
set colorbox vertical origin screen 0.9, 0.2, 0 size screen 0.05, 0.6, 0 front  noinvert bdefault
x = 0.0
# Last datafile plotted: "$grid"
splot 'data.tsv' using 1:2:3
```

However, the above script is giving me the following error:

```
"3d.gp", line 37: warning: No usable data in this plot to auto-scale axis range

splot 'data.tsv' using 1:2:3 
                             ^
"3d.gp", line 37: All points z value undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format the `data.tsv` file like this :

```
640000  1024    5220
640000  2048    3597
640000  4096    4088

320000  1024    7284
320000  2048    4940
320000  4096    3373

160000  1024    8417
160000  2048    5128
160000  4096    4661
```

and plot the data with

```
splot 'data.tsv' using 1:2:3  w l
```

I did a sucessful test just with that last gnuplot command... if you want something more fancy, I can try to help